# Does IBM's Sterling Web Forms have an API?

Tags: api

*Sterling Web Forms* is a web-based messaging system for large companies to send invoices/orders/notices/etc. to vendors from their ERP systems.

I have an app that would benefit from accessing the messages sent to me programmatically. Assuming there's an API for interfacing with it, **where is this publicly documented?**

I get the sense that this exists but I'm not searching with the right Enterprise-y terminology or product names...

Comment: Tried http://www.ibm.com/search/csass/search?sn=mh&q=sterling%20web%20form%20api&lang=en&cc=us&en=utf and 3rd link (Sterling Web™ Implementation Guide) is what you looking for?

Comment: @YvesR I don't think that's the same product as `Web Forms`. Also, I don't see any programmable API in there, either. If I missed it, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: I haven't been able to find an api for sterling web forms. However, I have found one for IBM forms. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lfwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_IBM_Forms_API_API_8_DG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a IBM product called IBM Sterling Direct Connect which might be of huge help to you.

http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/documentation_expanded_list/software/other_software/sterling_connect:direct

it had docs for .net and java

Answer (score 1):

1. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/sb2bsvcs/v1r0/index.jsp

"IBM Sterling B2B Services User Guides","Using IBM Sterling Web Forms","IBM Sterling Web Forms FAQs"